# Laravel updateTimestamps method unneccessary checks?

Tags: php, laravel

Digging trough the source of laravel I found this method:

```
protected function updateTimestamps()
{
    $time = $this->freshTimestamp();
    if (! is_null(static::UPDATED_AT) && ! $this->isDirty(static::UPDATED_AT)) {
        $this->setUpdatedAt($time);
    }
    if (! $this->exists && ! is_null(static::CREATED_AT) &&
        ! $this->isDirty(static::CREATED_AT)) {
        $this->setCreatedAt($time);
    }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasTimestamps.php#L37-L49)

The method pulls a new timestamp and tries to update both `created_at` and `updated_at`. However, the checks done in the if statements to not make sense to me.

1. Why do we have to check if `static::UPDATED_AT` / `static::CREATED_AT` is not null? Its defined as `const` on the Model class where this trait is used (its not used anywhere else and even if: without `static::UPDATED_AT` and `static::CREATED_AT` this whole trait does nothing at all so there is no point in using it in the first place)
2. why do we check if the column is not dirty? In my opinion it doesnt matter if the column is dirty. Because an update is an update and the "most fresh" call to `updateTimestamps()` should "win" which is not the case here because later calls are ignored (because the column is already dirty)

So why are these checks there?

Comment: Some scenario's do actually care if the dates are dirty. importing data from other sources comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You may not have an `updated_at` type field on a table. Would be no reason for eloquent to try and set that field then and it needs a way to know not to do it ... `static::UPDATED_AT == null`

You could want an `updated_at` type field, but not a `created_at` type field ... so inverse of that example.

2) Checking for dirty is so you can set those fields directly. Perhaps I want to set one of those fields to a specific value, not automatically set a timestamp to `now`.

Comment: `static::UPDATED_AT` is a `const`. How could a user possibly change that?

Comment: I guess child Models can change this const value by overring it, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, there is an example of setting those 2 `const`s on your models in the [Eloquent Documentation - Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)